# Appium - Mobile Automation Testing - Android - Selected property of the selected tab of a tab bar is always false

Tags: java, selenium, appium-android

Appium tool - Selected property of a tab bar is always false for all the tabs irrespective of which is selected. Is there any other way to verify if a tab bar is selected or not .? (e.g, Similar scenario or the tab bar can be observed in whats app like Chats,Status,Calls)

Comment: Observe the change in any of the attribute of the select node, once you select and deselect and use that attribute for validation.

Comment: Screen shot would be helpful to help you.